# Create an Azure AD B2C (Preview) User Programmatically

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I've recently being trying to create a user in my Azure AD B2C (Preview) instance programmatically.  The part that's holding me back is simply trying to retrieve a token.  So far I've tried:

```
var clientId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
var clientSecret = @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var tenant = "xxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com";

var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenant);

var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);

var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://graph.windows.net", credential);
```

When execution hits the last line to try acquire a token, I get:

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalServiceException: AADSTS70001: Application 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' is not supported for this API version.

What can I deduce from this error?  Does it mean that Graph access has been temporarily removed for Azure AD B2C?  Or do I need to enable something?  Or do I have one of the endpoint URLs wrong?

Comment: Are you using ADAL v2? this is required for Graph API, not ADAL v4 (which is required for B2C), otherwise, I assume you followed this tutorial: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet/ which works for our B2C to create users

Comment: I have NuGet package Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory which is version 3.10.30516.  Do you know if I would need to follow all the Powershell steps shown in the sample?  They seem to be about setting up applications and client secret, which I seem to be able to do directly in the Azure blade.

Comment: Yes, you need to create a seperate application and client secret, the one in B2C isn't usable (not enough permissions), we are using the 2.x version of the ADAL library.

Comment: And it also works with the 3.10 ADAL version, I just did an upgrade to test this.

Comment: Fantastic thanks, your last 2 comments are the last piece of the puzzle for me.  Do you want to put your comments into an answer and I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For connecting to the Graph API, you need to setup a separate clientId and secret. Follow this B2C tutorial to create the service principal and attach the 3 Graph API permissions:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet/

Be sure to use ADAL v2 (or the just released ADAL v3), and not ADAL v4 which is just experimental for B2C.

In the future the MSAL library will combine all of this hopefully.

The following script allows you to create this in 1 powershell script:

```
$msolcred = Get-Credential
Connect-MsolService -credential $msolcred

$bytes = New-Object Byte[] 32
$rand = [System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator]::Create()
$rand.GetBytes($bytes)
$rand.Dispose()
$newClientSecret = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)

$principal = New-MsolServicePrincipal -DisplayName "Dummy" -Type password -Value $newClientSecret

Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId 88d8e3e3-8f55-4a1e-953a-9b9898b8876b -RoleMemberObjectId $principal.ObjectId -RoleMemberType servicePrincipal
Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId 9360feb5-f418-4baa-8175-e2a00bac4301 -RoleMemberObjectId $principal.ObjectId -RoleMemberType servicePrincipal
Add-MsolRoleMember -RoleObjectId fe930be7-5e62-47db-91af-98c3a49a38b1 -RoleMemberObjectId $principal.ObjectId -RoleMemberType servicePrincipal

Write-Host "clientsecret = $newClientSecret"
Write-Host "clientId     =  $(($principal).AppPrincipalId)"
Write-Host "tenant       = $((Get-MsolDomain).Name)"
```